# C++ lambda return type not what expected

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to get C++11 lambdas down.  I'm sure there is a way to initialize `temp` with a lambda (granted maybe not the best way), but I've been unable to come up with this solution.

The desired result:  *`temp` should contain an empty string for every element in `data`.*

Here is the way I would usually initialize `temp`:

```
vector<string> temp;
for(auto i : data){
  temp.push_back("");
}
```

Here is the closest (I believe) that I've come to a lambda solution:

```
auto num = data.size();  //can't pass class members (data) to capture list
auto temp = [num](vector<string> strs) -> vector<string> {
  for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    strs.push_back("");
  }
  return strs;
};
```

However, when I call `temp.size()`, I get the following error:

`struct ProteinAnalyzer::convert_sequences()::__lambda0’ has no member named ‘size’`
(using GCC 4.8.1)

I even explicitely declared the return type, so I'm puzzled as to why this lambda does not return `vector<string>`

Comment: You are confusing the type of the lambda with its return type.

Comment: just initialize your vector like this: `std::vector< std::string > temp( data.size(), "" );` here are all vector's constructors for your reference:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: `temp` is the lambda itself.

Comment: You can just call it; add `()` at the end and it should work. That's little difference over just writing the code, though, and that's a rather bad example for lambda usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I have figured out the solution to my problem.  Here is how I initialized `temp` with a lambda function if anyone is curious:

```
auto num = data.size();
auto temp = [num](){
  vector<string> temp;
  for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i){
    temp.push_back("");
  }
  return temp;
}();
```

My problem was that I was equating the lambda with its return - two separate things.

...Although, as mentioned in the comments, `vector<string> temp(data.size(), "");` is probably the best (most succint) way.